# Irregular xml file processing

Tags: c#, xml, xhtml, linq-to-xml

I need to process information from an XML-like file. Does anyone know some library/inbuild class (preferably c#) which might be useful to deal with that type of document (with not much effort)  ?

Below is a piece of the XML :

```
<query>
  <type id="excel" />
  <ids>
    <id value="47" />
    <id value="2067" />
    <id value="247" />
    <id value="329" />
    <id value="19" />
    <id value="485" />
    <id value="148" />
    <id value="203" />
    <id value="219" />
    <id value="1503" />
    <id value="7318" />
  </ids>
  <period value="Monthly" />
  <start month="01" year="1990" />
  <end month="12" year="2015" />
</query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :D

There are 2 tools that should help you in dealing with it :

- [XSD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will generate a schema and classes that you can add to your project
- [XSD2Code](https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) will generate classes from a schema as well as Serialize/Deserialize methods

**Suggestion :**

Use XSD.EXE to generate your schema then use XSD2Code to generate classes from that schema.

Both tools are free,

The first one you access it through the Developer Command Line :

```
xsd file.xml
```

[image]

The second one is a Visual Studio add-in : (tutorial on their site)

[image]

**Do not forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it or ask for more details by editing your question.**

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a perfectly valid XML file.

There are `System.Xml.XmlDocument` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), both deal with parsing (and constructing) XML.

You can also build a class model and then use `XmlSerializer` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to deserialize the xml into a class hierarchical model instance.

Comment: Again, why downvote (especially with no commentary)?

Comment: You don't give a chance to new users, you just down vote without providing an answer.

Comment: @Aybe I did not downvote this question (nor previous similar one - I only downvote questions that are extremely poor quality or please-do-my-homework-for-me type), and provided a reasonable answer. So there is no negative response from me on this question. How's my answer bad that it deserved downvote? (I'd like to know so I can avoid in the future)... And when you say I "downvoted without providing an answer" - that's simply not true as you're commenting to my answer in the first place.

Comment: Edit your question and I'll upvote you again because it's locked now.